# How to align buttons inside sticky footer

Tags: css

Tried to align buttons in left and center and right side but not working.How to align buttons left side and 
if i add more buttons for left, left button start from left side move to right side.

if i add more buttons for center, center button start from center side move to right side and left side.

if i add more buttons for right, right button start from right side move to left side side.

I want to show buttons properly on left side,center,right side.

If anyone know please help to find the solution?

```
  <footer class="footer">
   <div class="ct-footer-post">
      <div class="container">

         <div class="inner-left">

            <button>
            Left btn 1
            </button>

            <button>
             Left btn 2
            </button>

            <button>
             Left btn 3
            </button>

           </div>

         <div class="inner-center">

            <button>
            Center btn 1
            </button>

            <button>
             Center btn 2
            </button>

            <button>
             Center btn 3
            </button>

         </div>

         <div class="inner-right">

            <button>
             Right btn 1
            </button>

            <button>
             Right btn 2
            </button>

            <button>
             Right btn 3
            </button>

         </div>

      </div>
   </div>
</footer>
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/hpyksndj/8/

Comment: you can put your button in container with a fixed width.

Comment: Can you edit jsfiddle?

Comment: Hope it will help you. :) https://codepen.io/jaydeeep/pen/gObpxbE

Comment: What exactly you want ? not got your question

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Priyanka:I want to show the buttons properly left and center and right side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex box.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```